# SyntaxError: Unexpected token in ImportJson

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

cannot read JSON file, my JSON file:
https://bet.hkjc.com/football/getJSON.aspx?jsontype=search_result.aspx&startdate=20191013&enddate=20191013&teamid=default

```
function ImportJSONAdvanced(url, query, options, includeFunc, transformFunc)  {
      var jsondata = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
      var object   = JSON.parse(jsondata.getContentText());
      return parseJSONObject_(object, query, options, includeFunc, transformFunc);
}
```

> Error
>   SyntaxError: Unexpected token: in
>     var object   = JSON.parse(jsondata.getContentText());

I want read the json file

Comment: THis is a generic error that occurs when your JSON is malformed. Check the json in a validator.

Comment: I've copied your function and assigned `url` the value of `https://bet.hkjc.com/football/getJSON.aspx?jsontype=search_result.aspx&startdate=20191013&enddate=20191013&teamid=default` and I am not getting an error at all. Can you make sure that your url is being passed correctly? Where is `ImportJSONAdvanced()` being called from?

Comment: Can give me your google sheet??
i would like yo know you use importjson.js

Comment: Hello! Is this still happening? It seems like the link you provided returns a valid JSON object, so there should be no problems on your code.